# Cache issue with BigQuery Materialized View with allow_non_incremental_definition and manual refresh

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

We are using Materialized View with allow_non_incremental_definition set to true.
Defined similar to this

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW
  `project.dataset.table`
OPTIONS ( enable_refresh = TRUE,
    refresh_interval_minutes = 360,
    max_staleness = INTERVAL "6" HOUR,
    allow_non_incremental_definition = TRUE
```

time to time, we do manual refresh.

```
CALL BQ.REFRESH_MATERIALIZED_VIEW('project.dataset.table')
```

However after, for some GCP users, query continue to return data before refresh.

My expectation, that after refresh all cached data will be invalidated and latest will be returned.

Is it normal behavior or how can I ensure latest data after refresh ?

Answer (score 1):

If the users send the exact same query before and after the materialized view update, it's normal. [BigQuery caches the request](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cached-results) and serves from the cache result if you reuse the exact same query.

So, it's not a problem with Materialized views, but with BigQuery. You can force the request not to use the case. And, this time, your issue should be solved.

Comment: Thank you so much @guillaume blaquiere! Correct me if I wrong, this is not happens with normal table, cache will be invalidated when table got updated? I think MV should follow same logic. Biggest problem is our application, where we can not manipulate use cache on the fly.

Comment: Yes, cache is kept is to 24h in BigQuery. And Yes, if your application uses the same query and not handle cache invalidation, it can lead to an issue. Some application, like Looker Studio propose to control the cache (perform BigQuery query with cache ignore option). However, you have to implement the same feature in your application and use it often to have fresh data, but not always to benefit cached result and save money. Cache management is always difficult! https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cached-results#disabling_retrieval_of_cached_results

Comment: Thank you for your response, @guillaume blaquiere! I totally agree with you and it totally make sense to me, except this cache is not global, but per GCP user, as result same query for different users will produce different result. As a joke, if two of my data scientist got different result from same query, they first kill me and when each other. So far this is looks like bug to me, sorry, if I missing something crucial here!

Comment: Except if you use Enterprise Edition or Enterprise Plus Edition, you can share the cache across users (the feature as less than 1 month): https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cached-results#cross-user-caching